# How to extract word in a text with condition in matlab?

Tags: matlab, nlp, preprocessor

I have multiple text files, and just want to extract only a value with a condition,

the file look like this

```
157.76941498460488, u'id': 1056080, u'image_id': 354282, u'bbox':      [188.68243243243242, 229.17468354430378, 16.21621621621621, 9.729113924050637], u'legibility': u'illegible', u'class': u'machine printed'}, {u'language': u'na', u'area': 157.76941498460522, u'id': 1056081, u'image_id': 354282, u'bbox': [176.79054054054052, 241.06582278481014, 16.216216216216246, 9.729113924050637], u'legibility': u'illegible', u'class': u'machine printed'}, {u'language': u'na', u'area': 130.89018132056108, u'id': 1056082, u'image_id': 354282, u'bbox': [60.03378378378378, 224.8506329113924, 15.13513513513514, 8.648101265822783], u'legibility': u'illegible', u'class': u'machine printed'}, {u'language': u'english', u'area': 229.08553456429397, u'class': u'machine printed', u'utf8_string': u'7206', u'image_id': 354282, u'bbox': [447.84940154212785, 338.8799273943157, 15.489338584815993, 14.78988488177692], u'legibility': u'legible', u'id': 1232932}, {u'language': u'english', u'area': 125.41629858832702, u'class': u'machine printed', u'utf8_string': u'HSS', u'image_id': 354282, u'bbox': [465.63345695432395, 333.1362827800334, 10.039386119788142, 12.492427036063997], u'legibility': u'legible', u'id': 1232933}]
```

I want to extract all bboxs if its utf8_string, and the output store like this

```
bbox = [188.68243243243242, 229.17468354430378, 16.21621621621621, 9.729113924050637]
bbox1 = [60.03378378378378, 224.8506329113924, 15.13513513513514, 8.648101265822783]
..etc bbox3 and box4 all the bboxs if its 'utf8_string'and legible
```

my code

```
i=imread('image.JPEG');

fid = fopen('text1.txt','r');
C = textscan(fid, '%s','Delimiter','');
fclose(fid);
C = C{:};

box = ~cellfun(@isempty, strfind(C,'bbox'));

output = [C{find(box)}]
```

I'm getting the whole line not only the bbox.

Comment: Why are you specifying an empty delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code sample that does this extraction using regex. It is probably not the fastest on earth, neither the most robust, but If your text file is small, it does the job. It gives you an idea on how you can proceed in such situation, and amend the code so that is works fully with you data if necessary.

I suppose that you have a list of files in     `[filepathList]`

```
Cdata = cell(numel(filepathList),1);
for i=1:numel(filepathList)
    fid = fopen(filepathList{i});
    tline = fgetl(fid);

    % find the bbox blocks
    C = regexp(tline,'u''bbox'': +\[([0-9\. ,]+)\]','tokens');
    C = cellfun(@(x) x{1},C,'UniformOutput',false)';

    % in each block, find the numbers
    C2 = cellfun(@(x) textscan(x,'%f','Whitespace',', '),C,'UniformOutput',false);
    Cdata{i} = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x', cat(1,C2{:}),'UniformOutput',false));
    fclose(fid);
end
```

Hope this help !

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and for easy understandable code, It's run perfectly with the example above. However, when I start to run it with different text it give me an ERROR  `Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent`

Comment: I amend the code so that it works with your second example also

Comment: Thanks a lot it works like charm, my last question is, how to generalize it, I have more 10k files like this one, and try it to run it in a loop. Thanks for advance

Comment: You should probably rewrite the question so that it fits more your problem. You suggested that you have only one big file. If it answer the specific question, you can accept the answer